# Testing The Trained Neural Network - Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to use the neural network to classify handwritten digits of [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) dataset

I have created 2 layer neural network with 100 hidden unit and trained it using 60,000 * 784 trainImages matrix and 60,000 * 1 trainLabels

```
net = newff(trainImages,trainLabels,100)
```

how to test and calculate the error rate of the trained network with 10,000 * 784 testImages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Training:

```
[net,tr]=train(net,trainImages',trainLabels');
```

Testing:

```
PredictedLabels = sim(net,testImages');
error_rate = 1- mean(PredictedLabels == testLabels');
```

Comment: i tried that and it gives me Inputs are incorrectly sized for network.
Matrix must have 60000 rows error

Comment: transpose all your matrices: trainImages, trainLabels, testImages, testLabels. Make the column as your sample number